# AWS Lambda NodeJS launch EMR Spark Problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-emr

I am trying to launch an EMR cluster with the following script in Lambda (NodeJS-12).

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var emr = new AWS.EMR({apiVersion: '2009-03-31', region: 'ap-northeast-1'});
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
        "Name": "LaunchEMR",
        "Instances": {
            "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": true,
            "TerminationProtected": false,
            "Ec2SubnetId": "subnet-XXXXXXXX",
            "EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup": "ElasticMapReduce-master",
            "EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup": "ElasticMapReduce-slave",
            "HadoopVersion": "2.8.5",
            "InstanceGroups": [{
                "Name": "Master",
                "InstanceRole": "MASTER",
                "InstanceCount": 1,
                "InstanceType": "m3.xlarge",
                "Market": "ON_DEMAND"
            }, {
                "Name": "Core",
                "InstanceRole": "CORE",
                "InstanceCount": 1,
                "InstanceType": "m3.xlarge",
                "Market": "ON_DEMAND"
            }]
        },
        "Applications": [{
            "Name": "Hadoop"
        }, {
            "Name": "Spark"
        }],
        "ServiceRole": "EMR_DefaultRole",
        "JobFlowRole": "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole",
        "ReleaseLabel": "emr-5.28.0"
    };
    emr.runJobFlow(params)
        .on('success', function(response){ console.log("success => " + response); console.log(response); })
        .on('error', function(response){ console.log("error => " + response); console.log(response); })
        .on('complete', function(response){ console.log("complete => "  + response); console.log(response); })
        .send( function(err, data){
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     console.log(data);           // successful response
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(err),
            });
        });
};
```

I had tuned the IAM policies can I seem to be able to submit the request successfully to EMR, as there is no error in the Lambda cloud-watch log, and we can see the request in EMR events.
However, we will get a cluster termination event right after the request event.

[image: error image]

Error Log

```
Amazon EMR Cluster j-31OE0F3OXGO4K (LaunchEMR) has terminated with errors at 2019-12-02 06:32 UTC with a reason of VALIDATION_ERROR.
```

The SubnetID and Security-Group are the same as my manually started clusters.
I added the "iam:PassRole" in "EMR_DefaultRole".
I also tried some other instance types.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to successfully run it by taking these 3 lines off.

```
            "Ec2SubnetId": "subnet-XXXXXXXX",
            "EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup": "ElasticMapReduce-master",
            "EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup": "ElasticMapReduce-slave",
```

But I still have no idea why it works. (and why it doesn't)